# Azure AD SAML Authentication with Spring Security 5.3.2 (not SAML Extension)

Tags: spring-security, spring-oauth2

I am attempting to replace [CAS](https://apereo.github.io/cas) with [Azure Active Directory SAML authentication (SSO)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-single-sign-on-non-gallery-applications) in a [Spring Boot API](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/).  My version of Spring Security is 5.3.2.  Spring boot is 2.3.0.

Documentation has been hard to find.  I think this is explained by [8685](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/8685).  I found [8010](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/8010) and attempted the workaround mentioned there, but my breakpoints there are not getting hit.

Given the current state of the transition from SAML Extension to Spring Security, should I be using the old SAML Extension?  I can reach my "success" endpoint with a JSESSIONID and SAMLReponse, but it's encrypted.  Is this something I need to do myself?  (If so, how?) The SecurityContext / user details are not getting set.  I see AccessDenied stack traces in my logs, but I think that's a symptom of the Anonymous user context.

Relevant code is below.  I have application.yml and application.properties files, but all config is annotations-based.  If you see anything way off base, please let me know!  Any guidance would be appreciated.

Here is my SecurityConfig:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    RelyingPartyRegistration getSaml2AuthenticationConfiguration() throws Exception {
        // remote IDP entity ID
        String idpEntityId = "https://sts.windows.net/xxxxxxxxxxxx/";
        // remote WebSSO Endpoint - Where to Send AuthNRequests to
        String webSsoEndpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxxxxxx/saml2";
        // local registration ID
        String registrationId = "xxxxxxxxxxxx";
        // local entity ID - autogenerated based on URL
        String localEntityIdTemplate = "xxxxxxxxxxxx.local";
        // local signing (and decryption key)
        Saml2X509Credential signingCredential = getSigningCredential(); //private method not included
        // IDP certificate for verification of incoming messages
        Saml2X509Credential idpVerificationCertificate = getVerificationCertificate();  //private method not included
        String acsUrlTemplate = "https://xxxxxxxxxxxx.local/success"; //REST endpoint, see below
        return RelyingPartyRegistration.withRegistrationId(registrationId)
                .providerDetails(config -> config.entityId(idpEntityId))
                .providerDetails(config -> config.webSsoUrl(webSsoEndpoint)).credentials(c -> c.add(signingCredential))
                .credentials(c -> c.add(idpVerificationCertificate)).localEntityIdTemplate(localEntityIdTemplate)
                .assertionConsumerServiceUrlTemplate(acsUrlTemplate).build();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        // Just a test
        OpenSamlAuthenticationProvider provider = new OpenSamlAuthenticationProvider();

        http
            .headers()
            .frameOptions()
            .sameOrigin()
            .httpStrictTransportSecurity()
            .disable()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            //... more antMatchers and permitAlls
            .antMatchers("/success").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/logout").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/error").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .saml2Login(
                    saml2 -> {
                        try {
                            saml2
                            .authenticationManager(a -> {
                                // This code is never reached
                                Authentication result = provider.authenticate(a);
                                Saml2Authentication saml2Authentication = (Saml2Authentication) result;
                                return result; 
                            }).relyingPartyRegistrationRepository(
                                    new InMemoryRelyingPartyRegistrationRepository(getSaml2AuthenticationConfiguration())
                            )
                            .loginProcessingUrl("/login/{registrationId}");
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // It made me put this try/catch here... this isn't getting reached either
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    });
    }

}
```

And my REST endpoint:

```
@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/success", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saml2Post(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
        String jSessionId = request.getHeader("cookie");
        System.out.println(jSessionId);
        
        String samlResponse = request.getReader().lines().collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
        System.out.println(samlResponse);
        
        return "login success";
    }

}
```

And my gradle dependencies (Gradle 6.5):

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    
    compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-config'
    compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-saml2-service-provider'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compile 'org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-freemarker'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-integration'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail'
    compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-client'
    compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-jose'
    implementation 'joda-time:joda-time:2.10.6'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:29.0-jre'
    implementation 'com.opencsv:opencsv:5.2'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.10'
    implementation 'net.minidev:json-smart:2.3'

    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    runtimeOnly 'com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc'
    runtimeOnly 'org.hsqldb:hsqldb'
    providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
}
```

Comment: Would you be able to put that together into a GitHub sample? I'd be happy to run it locally and see where it's getting stopped up. Also, you mentioned that it's encrypted, but I don't see a decryption key in your RelyingPartyRegistration.

Comment: Side note: The reason the DSL is requiring you to catch an exception is because your `getSaml2AuthenticationConfiguration` method throws `Exception`.

Comment: I took your SecurityConfig and added it to the Spring Security saml2login sample, pushing it too my fork. It's not quite the same as your scenario, but it may be something that we can iterate off of: https://github.com/jzheaux/spring-security/tree/so-62544948/samples/boot/saml2login

Comment: I wonder if `getSaml2AuthenticationConfiguration` is throwing an exception, and that's why the authentication manager isn't getting wired.